# Error while trying to deploy the angular app in a azure vm:

Tags: angular, deployment, server, production-environment

I have developed an angular app in my local machine. I am trying to deploy my angular app in a vm. I have install node and npm in the server. I have followed a tutorial - https://coursetro.com/posts/code/112/Angular-5-Deployment---Deploy-your-Angular-App

I have created the dist folder using

```
ng build --prod
```

Then transferred the folder produced in dist to the server under a folder test.

I ran the command

```
ng build --prod --base-href "/test/".
```

But this gives an error

```
The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.
```

Where am I going wrong? Is the location where I am trying to build is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running ng build twice is wrong. Run it once, take the dist output and deploy it to a web server like nginx. Installing npm and node on your server is also not needed, unless you have a node backend.

Comment: I am deploying an app for the first time, so I didn't completely understand `deploy it to a web server like nginx.` I have transferred the files in dist folder to a folder named test on server. Then I tried `http://ip//test/frontendApp/index.html` in a browser. but couldn't load the app.

Comment: 3 questions: 1) What kind of server? 2) Which folder on the server? 3) What do you mean by 'couldnt load the app'? What did you see in your browser?

Comment: 1) I am trying to deploy on Azure vm. 2) I have created a folder called test on the server and copied the content of dist folder produced by ng build in local. 3)Browser says site can't be reached, ''ip" refused to connect.